# unable to copy the following message shows: "no such file or directory"

Tags: command-line

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 server to host an open source human resources software with 20 computers on our office network.  I am new to Linux and I really need everyone's help!

```
sudo cp -R /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/sites/blank /var/lib/iHRIS/sites/manage
```

I'm using the above command to copy but the following message shows:

```
"cp: cannot stat ‘/var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/sites/blank’: No such file or directory"
```

What did I miss?!  Everyone's kind assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Have You checked file is locate under this location? (/var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/sites/blank)

Comment: check all the directory names exactly as it is or not (case sensitive), see if there are any space in between directory names.

Comment: Thank you everyone! There is a compressed file with extension tar.bz2 in folder 4.1.9, if I uncompressed this file it will show the "ihris-manage folder and all subfolders, but I try to uncompressed it but there is a message saying that "you don't have the right permission to extract archive in this folder". What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to prevent typos is to only type the first few letters of the first folder in the path, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete the rest of the folder's name. I then do the same thing with the next folder, and the next folder, et cetera, until I'm able to auto-complete the the file at the end of the path. It's a lot quicker than typing the path manually, and it's far less likely to result in errors. 
Honestly, I don't know how CLI users used to get along without tab-completion.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spelling and case of the file/directory path your are trying to copy. This is most likely due to a mistyped file/directory path. Remember that Linux is case-sensitive, and if you have any spaces in a file/directory names you must put the path in quotes:

```
sudo cp -R "/home/username/some folder name/"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I did check everything and everything seem to be in order, the path and folders etc...but there is a compressed file withe extension *.tar.bz2 which I have to uncompressed in folder 4.1.9, I try to uncompressed it but there is a message saying that "you don't have the right permission to extract archive in this folder".  What do I have to do?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to type in the shell

```
ls -l /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/sites/blank
```

it would probably say that the file does not exist. So go up one element in the path and do

```
ls -l /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/sites/
```

...it should list all the files in this directory. If still gives you an error, try with

```
ls -l /var/lib/iHRIS/lib/4.1.9/ihris-manage/
```

...and so on. You got the idea, you are bound to find the part of your pathname which is wrong or mispelled.